# Adobe AIR Android Bluetooth Serial Data Communication

Tags: air, bluetooth, serial-port, adobe

Hi does any one know if there any way to get access to Bluetooth serial port via Adobe Air on Android (or iOS)?

Comment: I have the same question. Let me know if you found a way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a solution [which doesn't involve writing a native extension myself] for Android yet, but for iOS, you could use [this native extension](https://github.com/jamieowen/AirNativeiOS-Bluetooth).

---

#### Demo

[image: Video demo]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tdh0DBYAtOo